# React put method not updating the user from Django

Tags: django, reactjs, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django as backend and updating the user from postman is working fine. But when I update it via React Frontend, it replies with a success message just as in Postman, but the data was not updated.

This is the update function to update:

```
  const updateData = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const csrftoken = getCookie("csrf");
const cookies = new Cookies();
const url = "http://localhost:8000/usercontrol/update";
setIsLoading(true);
fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: "Token " + cookies.get("token"),
    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: userinfo.email,
    username: userinfo.username,
    first_name: userinfo.first_name,
    last_name: userinfo.last_name,
  }),
}).then((response) => console.log("THE RESPONSE: ", response.json()));
setIsLoading(false);
};
```

This is what it prints out in the console

[image]

Since I am partially following CodingWithMitch for Django user creation with rest framework is similar to [his](https://github.com/mitchtabian/CodingWithMitchBlog-REST-API/tree/User-Account-Serializer-(Django-Rest-framework)/src/account).
Furthermore, since there is no error outputting and is working fine in Postman, I have no idea what is wrong with it.

Comment: @NyaSol Ugh, isn't the promiseValue the one I've shown in the picture? It'll only return that response from the backend. And I think it is not a fetch problem, right? I have used axios for the last project, and I just want to see the differences and so far, I have not encountered an error regarding specifically to fetch

Comment: What does the view look like?

Comment: Please after this line

Comment: it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/z04qNx1 and it's showing success. And in the Postman, the data gets saved. But in React frontend, the data isn't.